# Jface tableviewer - Scroll bars are not appearing when the window is being resized

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, tableviewer

I am using a jface tableviewer with a tablecolumnlayout (for it's parent composite) in my eclipse RCP application as follows -

```
    Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().numColumns(2).applyTo(composite);
    GridDataFactory.swtDefaults().grab(true, true).applyTo(composite);

    // Table Composite
    Composite tblComposite = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().numColumns(2).applyTo(tblComposite);
    GridDataFactory.swtDefaults().grab(true, true).hint(500, 180).applyTo(tblComposite);

    // Table Column Layout
    TableColumnLayout tableColumnLayout = new TableColumnLayout();
    tblComposite.setLayout(tableColumnLayout);

    tableViewer =
        new TableViewer(tblComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | 
                        SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.RESIZE);

    Table table = tableViewer.getTable();
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).applyTo(table);

    // Column 1
    TableViewerColumn column = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
    column.getColumn().setText("Source");
    tableColumnLayout.setColumnData(column.getColumn(), new ColumnWeightData(50, true));

    // Column 2
    TableViewerColumn column2 = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
    column2.getColumn().setText("Target");
    tableColumnLayout.setColumnData(column2.getColumn(), new ColumnWeightData(50, true));

    tableViewer.setUseHashlookup(true);
    tableViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
    tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new CustomLabelProvider());
    tableViewer.setSorter(new CustomViewSorter());
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I resize the window (reduce the size of the window) I'm not seeing Vertical and Horizontal scrollbars for the table viewer, that is even when the rows of the table are not seen when resizing (shrinking the size until some rows from table are hidden), the scrollbars don't appear at all but we generally expect them to appear right?

Is there anything wrong in GridData logic I have used? Please help me get unstuck here.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in this, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help.

Comment: I will now edit my question and add a more complete code, but I'm not quite sure where the problem is in the code.

Comment: I have added a more complete code, I feel there's a problem in the combination of GridData, GridLayout and TableColumnLayout, could you guide me in the right path? I also tried adding this style constant SWT.RESIZE to tableViewer but I still do not get the scroll bars when the window is resized.

Comment: I'm still trying out various combinations to get past the issue I'm facing but in vain until now.. Code seems right to me but I do not understand if there's a minor glitch in the code that's disallowing Operating System from showing scrollbars when the window is resized.

Comment: Table/TableViewer does not support SWT.RESIZE flag, don't specify unsupported flags they can cause problems. We really need something we can run and test. Is this a Dialog?

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing out SWT.RESIZE, I will remove that.

Comment: Yes this is a dialog.. org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog

Comment: Also does my code have the functionality where the shell or composite would resize its children when the window size is reduced? I'm not very familiar with GridData, GridLayout. Sorry if it's a trivial question. In my case when I resize the window the table would go out-of-sight and the composite does not resize its child which is a table in this case.

Comment: Yes, resize should work with Grid layout. But it is easy to get things wrong and it is not always easy to see what it is that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Remove SWT.FULL_SELECTION. It does not work with SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL.